# Error on "," Consider adding "Expression"

Tags: processing

I'm trying to make a small maths game for my sister, and as of now, I have a class for the difficulty levels and one for Exercises. But when I try to set up a difficulty level in line 4, I get "Error on "," Consider adding "Expression"". What does this mean and how do I fix it? I'm using Processing 3.5.4

```
  background(#FFFFFF);
  size(1280, 720);
  DifficultyLevel easy = new DifficultyLevel(10, ['+']);
}

class DifficultyLevel {
  int maxNumber;
  Character[] allowedOperators;

  DifficultyLevel (int mN, Character[] aO) {
    maxNumber=mN+1;
    allowedOperators=aO;
  }

  Exercise generateExcercise() {
    return new Exercise((int) random(maxNumber), (int) random(maxNumber), allowedOperators[(int) random(allowedOperators.length)]);
  }
}

class Exercise {
  int numberOne;
  int numberTwo;
  Character operator;

  Exercise(int one, int two, Character op) {
    numberOne=one;
    numberTwo=two;
    operator=op;
    if (numberOne < numberTwo && op=='-') {
      numberOne=numberOne+numberTwo;
      numberTwo=numberOne-numberTwo;
      numberOne=numberOne-numberTwo;
    }
  }

  boolean checkResult(float in) {
    float res=0;
    switch(operator) {
    case '+':
      res = numberOne + numberTwo;
      break;
    case '-':
      res = numberOne - numberTwo;
      break;
    case '·':
      res = numberOne * numberTwo;
      break;
    case '÷':
      res= numberOne / numberTwo;
    }
    return res==in;
  }
}
```

By the way, I know the code for generating exercises is bad, I'm gonna improve it later.

Comment: You have to create an array of characters: `Character[] charArray = {'+'};`. Finally you can use the array: `DifficultyLevel easy = new DifficultyLevel(10, charArray);`

Comment: thank you! it works now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression statement `DifficultyLevel easy = new DifficultyLevel(10, ['+']);` is syntactically incorrect.

You have to create an array of characters

```java
Character[] charArray = {'+'};
```

Finally you can use the array:

```java
DifficultyLevel easy = new DifficultyLevel(10, charArray);
```